# Creating an array by placing multiple variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables, addition

This is most definitely a very basic question but I am missing something small and not able to find the problem.

I have 8 variables coming in as parameters which are put in an array and passed to Datatables Add row function. Surprisingly, if a concatenate a character before or after the variable and then put it in the array, the row is added but if I simply put the variables in array it does not work. For a workaround solution, I am pre and post suffixing a space to the variables and then timing it and this works. I have checked the type of variables using `console.warn(typeof(var))`, they all are `string`.Please see me code below with inline comments.

```
function AddRowinDt(ProcDate,Area, Surf,Proc,Desc,Prov,Status,Notes){
    //The following does not work but should work!!
    //var data=[ProcDate,Area,Surf,Proc,Desc,Prov,Status,'000'];
    //The following works as I am adding a character before and after the variable and then trimming it. 
    var data=[' '+ProcDate+' '.trim(),' '+Area+' '.trim(),' '+Surf+' '.trim(),' '+Proc+' '.trim(),' '+Desc+' '.trim(),' '+Prov+' '.trim(),' '+Status+' '.trim(),'000'];
    var rowNode = Dt.row.add(data).draw().node();
    $( rowNode )
     .css( 'color', 'red' )
     .animate( { color: 'blue' } , 2000);
 }
```

The question is: Why the concatenation of a character to the variables works, why not simply placing the variables in array works!!! What am I missing?

Comment: ```data[2]Surf;``` should be ```data[2]=Surf;```

Comment: that was a typo which I had already fixed. thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the post. problem persists :(

Comment: what is your problem? (be specific) [http://jsfiddle.net/yc4ttyu5/](http://jsfiddle.net/yc4ttyu5/) here are 3 different versions of preparing the array and they all work. Is your issue with the ```Dt.row.add(data).draw()```?

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` return if you run it before the add?

Comment: Its shows correct data as this: Array [ "23-Oct-14", "28", "IB", "MT", "MT Spec", "33", "C", "ll" ].

Comment: @cbayram My problem is populating the array which I pass to the add row method(reference your fiddle: AddRowInDt2 and AddRowInDt methods). If I hard code values or concatenate them with single quote, it works. Just did the output on console.log and all my data is correct. The fiddle you created is primarily for Datatables related issues but I am not facing issues there rather at passing data to datatables.

Comment: @FaisalKhan, If your array is correct (which it is), it's really difficult to assist you in why your passing the data to your datatables to create a new row. According to the [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), you are doing the right thing. However, without seeing your DT setup and columns it's difficult to help you. Perhaps you have a column (type/count) mismatch. Try ```Dt.columns()``` to view your columns. Perhaps someone else can chime in. Otherwise, I suggest you debug step by step using Dev tools. Good luck and hope you figure it out.

Comment: @cbayram I managed to get the desired result but one of the most funny and strange way and still fail to understand why this workaround works!!! here is how I am making the "data" array now:    var data=[' '+ProcDate+' '.trim(),' '+Area+' '.trim(),' '+Surf+' '.trim(),' '+Proc+' '.trim(),' '+Desc+' '.trim(),' '+Prov+' '.trim(),' '+Status+' '.trim(),'000'];   I am adding spaces on both sides and then trimming it and now I can add the row in datatables on the fly!!!!  this still beats me!!!!!! any clues!!!!!

Comment: @FaisalKhan, glad to see you are making progress. Looks like your array values need to be of type string. Have you tried printing out the types of your array variables? ```console.warn(typeof(ProcDate))```,```console.warn(typeof(Area))```,... Is ProcDate type string or object?

Comment: @cbayram All parameters are string. Thanks for your follow up messages and tips. I will update the original question for others to add their two cents. Cheers!